# How to change page orientation and number of pages of print composer layout using pyqgis in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am writing a qgis layout script to export my results in a pdf. I am using the tutorial provided [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html#output-using-print-layout) but this tutorial do not teach how to turn the page orientation from landscape to portrait.

my code is like this, it works but creates with a landscape orientation

```
import os

p = QgsProject()
layout = QgsLayout(p)
layout.initializeDefaults()

# create a map and stretch it over the whole paper size
map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
layout.addItem(map)

# picture
pic = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
pic.setPicturePath("C:\\Users\\c.png")
pic.setLinkedMap(map)
pic.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(1.4, 1.8, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutCentimeters))
pic.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(10, 10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutCentimeters))
layout.addItem(pic)


# label
label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
label.setText("hello")
label.adjustSizeToText()
label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(15, 1, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutCentimeters))
layout.addItem(label)


# export the pdf
pdf_path = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "output.pdf")
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf(pdf_path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

How can i change the pages to portrait orientation. And how can i add new pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Open python console in QGis, click show editor to open a new script and execute this script.

```
# create layout
p = QgsProject()
layout = QgsLayout(p)
layout.initializeDefaults()

# change first page orientation to portrait
pc = layout.pageCollection()
pc.page(0).setPageSize('A4', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Portrait)

# insert new landscape page
page = QgsLayoutItemPage(layout)
page.setPageSize('A4', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Landscape)
layout.pageCollection().addPage(page)

# export the pdf
pdf_path = "C:\\Users\\output.pdf"
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf(pdf_path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```